# Arch Linux boot failure: Fsck check on LVM /var mount fails

Tags: arch-linux, boot, lvm, fsck

I recently installed Arch Linux on an older laptop that I am using as a personal workstation and machine to better learn how to administer Linux.

I have a persistent boot failure that has started since I installed Arch Linux, however it ONLY happens every other boot.  When it does happen the Systemd.fsck job times out on the LVM volume I created for the /var mount at which point it goes into Emergency mode.  Until now I have just been restarting but it got annoying so I figured I would post what I could here and see if the problem is apparent.

There are no other operating systems and I am using Grub for the bootloader.  The partition tables are listed below.

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2                     47G  2.7G   42G   7% /
dev                          1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
run                          1.8G  468K  1.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                        1.8G  8.0K  1.8G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/volgrp1-lv_var    20G  1.1G   18G   6% /var
/dev/sda1                    656M   46M  563M   8% /boot
/dev/mapper/volgrp1-lv_home  227G  1.5G  214G   1% /home
tmpfs                        356M  4.0K  356M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Here is the relevant section of journalctl for the failed boot:

```
Jan 22 22:03:33 dustin-laptop kernel: USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
Jan 22 22:03:33 dustin-laptop lvm[205]: 2 logical volume(s) in volume group "volgrp1" now active
Jan 22 22:04:57 dustin-laptop systemd[1]: Job dev-mapper-volgrp1\x2dlv_home.device/start timed out.
Jan 22 22:04:57 dustin-laptop systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-mapper-volgrp1\x2dlv_home.device.
Jan 22 22:04:57 dustin-laptop systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /home.
Jan 22 22:04:57 dustin-laptop systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
Jan 22 22:04:57 dustin-laptop systemd[1]: Job dev-mapper-volgrp1\x2dlv_var.device/start timed out.
Jan 22 22:04:57 dustin-laptop systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-mapper-volgrp1\x2dlv_var.device.
Jan 22 22:04:57 dustin-laptop systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /var.
Jan 22 22:04:57 dustin-laptop systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Load/Save Random Seed.
Jan 22 22:04:57 dustin-laptop systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
Jan 22 22:04:57 dustin-laptop systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage.
Jan 22 22:04:57 dustin-laptop systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
Jan 22 22:04:57 dustin-laptop systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill0.
Jan 22 22:04:57 dustin-laptop alsactl[237]: /usr/bin/alsactl: load_state:1677: Cannot open /var/lib/alsa/asound.state for reading: No such file or directory
Jan 22 22:04:57 dustin-laptop alsactl[237]: /usr/bin/alsactl: sysfs_init:48: sysfs path '/sys' is invalid
Jan 22 22:04:57 dustin-laptop alsactl[237]: Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "IDT 92HD81B1X5" "HDA:111d7605,103c169a,00100107" "0x103c" "0x169a"
Jan 22 22:04:57 dustin-laptop alsactl[237]: Hardware is initialized using a generic method
Jan 22 22:04:58 dustin-laptop kernel: microcode: CPU0: new patch_level=0x05000119
Jan 22 22:04:58 dustin-laptop kernel: microcode: CPU1: new patch_level=0x05000119
Jan 22 22:04:58 dustin-laptop systemd[239]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /bin/plymouth: No such file or directory
```

Now here is the same relevant section related to the LVM var mount on a clean boot:

```
Jan 22 22:20:10 dustin-laptop kernel: rt2800pci 0000:06:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
Jan 22 22:20:11 dustin-laptop systemd-fsck[196]: /dev/sda1: clean, 360/43776 files, 18545/174744 blocks
Jan 22 22:20:11 dustin-laptop systemd[1]: var.mount: Directory /var to mount over is not empty, mounting anyway.
-- Subject: Mount point is not empty
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- The directory /var is specified as the mount point (second field in
-- /etc/fstab or Where= field in systemd unit file) and is not empty.
-- This does not interfere with mounting, but the pre-exisiting files in
-- this directory become inaccessible. To see those over-mounted files,
-- please manually mount the underlying file system to a secondary
-- location.
Jan 22 22:20:11 dustin-laptop kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: data=ordered
Jan 22 22:20:12 dustin-laptop kernel: EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: data=ordered
Jan 22 22:20:12 dustin-laptop systemd-journal[140]: Permanent journal is using 80.0M (max allowed 1.9G, trying to leave 2.9G free of 17.5G available → current limit 1.9G).
Jan 22 22:20:13 dustin-laptop systemd-journal[140]: Time spent on flushing to /var is 475.798ms for 699 entries.
Jan 22 22:20:14 dustin-laptop kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: data=ordered
Jan 22 22:20:14 dustin-laptop kernel: media: Linux media interface: v0.10
Jan 22 22:20:14 dustin-laptop kernel: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
Jan 22 22:20:14 dustin-laptop kernel: uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HP Truevision HD (05c8:0348)
Jan 22 22:20:14 dustin-laptop kernel: input: HP Truevision HD as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/input/input18
Jan 22 22:20:14 dustin-laptop kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
Jan 22 22:20:14 dustin-laptop kernel: USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
Jan 22 22:20:14 dustin-laptop lvm[195]: 2 logical volume(s) in volume group "volgrp1" now active
Jan 22 22:20:14 dustin-laptop kernel: microcode: CPU0: new patch_level=0x05000119
Jan 22 22:20:14 dustin-laptop kernel: microcode: CPU1: new patch_level=0x05000119
```

Now what I happened to notice was that on the root mountpoint there appear to be files already inside of its /var directory and it warns as such.  I am not sure why that is but I am wondering if that might be related to the cause of the problem here.  If it is related how should I go about fixing it?  There is only 47GB allocated to the root partition and I know how logs and journals can get rather large.  I prefer them separate.  What are your thoughts?

Let me know if you would like to also see my fstab file.